# Is there any example of using StrictMode with React-Native?

Tags: react-native

As I know about it, This checks and gives warnings for React-Native code and its lifecycles.

I read about it from [What is StrictMode in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53183362/what-is-strictmode-in-react)

How can I use it in react native ?

Comment: You should be able to use it the same way as a ReactJS app. Just use `<React.StrictMode>` as some root node in your JSX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple example to use StrictMode in React Native
StrictMode can be directly imported from **React** and can used like wrapping up **View** inside it.

```
import React, {Component, StrictMode} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

class Example extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <StrictMode>
    <View />
   </StrictMode>
  );
 }
} 

export default Example;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!