# Reack hook useState (initializer function) called twice, even without altering the data at all?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Here [in this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-jang-zvdyx) I simply call `useState` with an initializer function:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(() => {
    console.log('Getting initial state...');

    return {};
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see from console, `useState` function is called twice. Is there any reason for that, it's the normal behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is StrictMode in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53183362/what-is-strictmode-in-react)

Comment: I believe that caused by `<React.StrictMode />`

Comment: Thanks for asking this question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by `Strict Mode` which is wrapping your `App`.

Under Strict mode react intentionally runs some lifecycle methods twice to help detect errors.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html):

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:

> Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
> Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
> Function component bodies
> State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
> Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

> Note:
> This only applies to development mode. Lifecycles will not be double-invoked in production mode.