# React render counter start with two

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been created a new React application using `create-react-app`, and i make a test with render counter.

Consider the following code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

let render = 0;

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  render++;

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}
      >{`Clicked ${counter} times`}</button>
      <p>{`Render counter: ${render}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

At my logic the `render` variable at the first time need be start with 1, but... it's start with 2, and after i click on the button the render counter go to 4 not 3.

In my knowledge the render counter should change after each render when the state change, and state change 1 time per click, can someone explain me what's wrong? or why it's occours?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/little-sky-squ82?file=/src/App.js

Thanks!

Comment: you have [`<React.StrictMode>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) enabled (in  index.js) which will result in double renders in development, but not in production. Also, there is a render before you are even able to click the button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is StrictMode in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53183362/what-is-strictmode-in-react)

Comment: thanks, now i understood!

Answer (score -1):

It should work properly:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const render = useRef(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    render.current++;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => setCounter((prevCount) => prevCount + 1)}
      >{`Clicked ${counter} times`}</button>
      <p>{`Render counter: ${render.current}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Try to `useRef()` to track render count and if you updating state that uses prev state don't to like this:`setCounter(counter + 1)`. You should do like this: `setCounter((prevCount) => prevCount + 1)` because it might make problems.