# After Updating on react 18 paypal button show twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-buttons

Hello everyone i want to ask about the issue that after updating my react app my PayPal-buttonv2 rendering couple of times and shows Strictmode issues, please guid me thanks in advance

react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of n which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-find-node
at div
at n (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD:2:114571)
at PayPalButton (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39195:5)
at li

Comment: This question could do with a lot more detail, but if you aren't using the official @paypal/react-paypal-js you should begin by using that. See its storybook examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61961751/10749726  What is StrictMode in React?

Comment: i have updated the question now it might be clear to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My team faced this same issue after we upgraded our app to React 18. If you're now seeing two PayPal buttons after upgrading to React 18, you should use https://github.com/paypal/react-paypal-js if you're not already. This solved the issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

Just by going back to react 17 button are now showing just normal but strickmode error still there